# Template specialization in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Having done a brief search on the following error code from GCC, a number of hits show questions asking for help for this problem, but nothing much concrete turns up:

`error: explicit specialization of non-template 'std::hash'`

It looks like std::hash is indeed a template, so the error is not clear on what the problem is.  Sample code to generate the message is below.  The GCC option, -std=c++0x, compiles the code just fine.  The problem being that I have an older compiler that does not support C++11 on one machine, so some clarification on why this does not compile would be useful.

An alternative might be to use inheritance instead of specialization, and if that is the only solution, then that would be nice to know, also.

```
#include <functional>

struct test
{
    int n;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
        struct hash<test>
        {
        };
}
```

Comment: What "older compiler" are you talking about? Older version of GCC? Or some completely different compiler?

Comment: Your question is basically "when I use C++11 it works, when I can't use C++11 it doesn't work, why?" ... the answer should be obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::hash`, and the unordered containers that use it, didn't exist before C++11. If you need to use a compiler that only understands C++98, then you can't use them.

Similar containers are available in TR1 and Boost.

Answer (score 5):

In later pre-C++11 versions of GCC the non-standard legacy `hash_set` and `hash_map` implementations were placed into namespace `__gnu_cxx`, not `std`. So the default hashing functor for that set of legacy containers is actually `__gnu_cxx::hash<T>`, not `std::hash<T>`. Moreover, AFAIK it is not a part of `<functional>`.

The emerging implementations of then-pre-standard `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` were residing in `std::tr1` namespace, which means that their version of `hash` functior was actually `std::tr1::hash<T>`, not `std::hash<T>`.

Decide whichever one you need, if you are using an older compiler.

So I'd guess that your `std` just happens to declare in `<functional>` some completely unrelated non-template name `hash`, which is causing the compiler to complain when you attempt to use it in template context.

Comment: There is no unrelated name `hash` in `<functional>`, G++ gives that error for an undeclared name.

Answer (score 2):

`std::hash` was only introduced in C++11. Thus there is no `template <typename T> struct hash { ... };` in `std` to specialize in C++98/C++03.